# Changing field name in XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need to create an xslt transform file that essentially reads an xml file and changes the field names while keeping the same field values, then outputs a new xml file with these changes. I am having difficulty getting the values from the second and third field tags. Here is the incoming xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AUTHENTICATOR> 
<LOGINID>johndoe</LOGINID> 
<DATE>20150601</DATE> 
<USERTOKEN>vLk3pRdlQXX1JcO2s1QzAJfU050></USERTOKEN> 
<USERINFO>
<field name="First" value="John"/> 
<field name="Last" value="Doe"/> 
<field name="mail" value="johndoe@hotmail.com"/> 
</USERINFO> 
</AUTHENTICATOR>
```

I need the outpur xml to have field names be 'FirstName', 'LastName' and 'Email' but retain the same values. Here is my xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF‐8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/AUTHENTICATOR">

<AUTHENTICATOR>
<LOGINID><xsl:value-of select="LOGINID"/></LOGINID>
<DATE><xsl:value-of select="DATE"/></DATE>
<USERTOKEN><xsl:value-of select="USERTOKEN"/></USERTOKEN>
<USERINFO>
            <xsl:element name="field">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">FirstName</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="USERINFO/field/@value"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:element name="field">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">LastName</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="USERINFO/field/@value"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:element name="field">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">Email</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="USERINFO/field/@value"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
</USERINFO>
</AUTHENTICATOR>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a simple:

```
<xsl:template match="/AUTHENTICATOR">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="LOGINID | DATE | USERTOKEN"/>
        <USERINFO>
            <field name="FirstName" value="{USERINFO/field[@name='First']/@value}"/>
            <field name="LastName" value="{USERINFO/field[@name='Last']/@value}"/>
            <field name="Email" value="{USERINFO/field[@name='mail']/@value}"/>
        </USERINFO>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```